# What does Stephen mean by the line "No man in England could be a slave"?

Tags: jonathan-strange-and-mr-norrell

In the excellent BBC series "Jonathan Strange and Mr. Norell", Stephen (the black guy) often repeats the line "No man in England could be a slave".  My question is, what does he mean by this?  Does he mean that slavery has been abolished in England? Or does he mean that life in England is so good that no one's condition should be considered slavery, even the condition of an actual slave?

While watching the show I assumed the second explanation, but on reflection the first is simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavery_in_Britain

> Somersett's case in 1772 held that no slave could be forcibly removed from Britain. This case was generally taken at the time to have decided that the condition of slavery did not exist under English law, and emancipated the remaining ten to fourteen thousand slaves or possible slaves in England and Wales, who were mostly domestic servants.

Slavery was pretty much eliminated in mainland England.

> However slavery elsewhere in the British Empire was not affected.

Until 1807 with the Slave trade act prohibiting transport (Total abolishment in the Empire in 1833).

As the series is set in early 19th century England, Slavery was no longer in affect in England.